# Append date and floats to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append a series with a date, to an empty dataframe where date is the index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [], 'Y1': [], 'Y2':[]})
df.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)

new_row = pd.Series(data=['2005-01-30', 0.2, 0.4], index=['date', 'Y1', 'Y2'])
df = df.append(new_row) # error is here
```

But `df.append(new_row)` only works if the `ignore_index` argument is True, but that's not what I want. I want the date to be inserted as the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the name of your series to the date, then append to the dataframe.

Remember to filter out the date index before you append:

```
new_row.name = new_row.date
df = df.append(new_row[new_row.index != 'date'])

print(df)

#              Y1   Y2
# date                
# 2005-01-30  0.2  0.4
```